# Collect ID with specific counts and complaints

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables, one has complaints(`case_dtl`) and the other has the products and its different versions(`install_dtl`). `user_id` is a column that can be used to join these two tables.

I'm required to calculate the number of users(`count`) that are on specific version of the product and the total number of complaints for that version of the product.

I can calculate the count for different versions by a simple `group by` but I'm struggling to "concatenate" user id's with this count and then join these user id's with the user id's in `case_dtl` table to collect the number of complaints for that specific version of the product.

I am trying to write this query  in Teradata SQL.

Here's a sample(I am terribly sorry for doing such a pathetic job in creating a table. I tried and would love any help in that too):

### case_dtl table(complaints):

### User_ID      |Complaint

1 |Yes

2 |Yes

3 |Yes

7 |Yes

### install_dtl table(software versions table):

### User_ID |      Version

1 | 10

2 | 11

3 | 10

4 | 11

5 | 11

6 | 10

7 | 10

8 | 10

9 | 10

10|10

And, I need output like this:

Output:

---

### Version |Complaint Count | User Count

10 |3|7

11 |1|3

Comment: What's the primary key on `case_dtl`? Or, maybe more to the point, does each complaint have a unique identifier, and, if so, what field is that? A little more schema information might be useful, and a mock up of your desired result set. [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: There's a field called `User_id` that is primary key. And, I need each version of the product to be a unique group, and should have total subscribers on that version of the product and total complaints for that version of the product. Product is fixed for now(say `X`). So, a sample output should be:

Group(Version), Total_Complaints_for_that_version, Total_Subscribers_for_that_version

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an outer join:

```
select
t1.version,
count (t2.user_id),
count (t1.user_id)
from
install_dtl t1
left join case_dtl t2
on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```